# Is there a Visual Studio C# equivalent of the Visual Studio C++ Makefile project

Tags: visual-studio-2005

In Visual C++ inside Visual Studio, one of the project subtypes is a "*Makefile Project*".

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Visual C# inside Visual Studio?

---

BTW, a Makefile project is:

> If you have a project that you build from the command line with a
>   makefile, then the Visual Studio development environment will not
>   recognize your project. To open and build your project using Visual
>   Studio, first create an empty project containing the appropriate build
>   settings using the Makefile Project Wizard. You can then use this
>   project to build your project from the Visual Studio development
>   environment.
>
> The project displays no files in Solution Explorer. The project
>   specifies the build settings, which are reflected in the project's
>   property page.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of `make` in Visual Studio world is `msbuild`. Visual Studio does not use `make`. `.csproj`, `.vbproj` etc. are input files for `msbuild`. You can do pretty much the same stuff in them as in conventional makefiles, including command line building, custom targets etc.

Comment: Yes - but that's not an option in the list when you "Create Project" inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Because VS doesn't need one. All its projects are 'Makefile' projects in a sense, the difference being that it uses msbuild instead of make.

Comment: I'm not talking about "make". I'm talking about a "Makefile project". Inside VS, if you select C++,  a Makefile project is one of the options. Inside VS, if you select C#, there is no such option. Or to put it another way, can you create a MSbuild project type for C#?

Comment: Continued: I'm asking this because a Makefile project is the way to run MSIL code (*.il) files inside VS. I don't want anything else in the project - just the .il files and the batch command (ilasm /debug) to build them.

Comment: You'll have to write your msbuild project by hand. Once it works with command-line msbuild, I think you can just add it to your solution, manually or give it a standard extension like .csproj.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing C++-specific about the Makefile project type; it just runs a command line.  It's just that it's listed along with the Visual C++ project types. You can add one to a solution that otherwise contains nothing but C# projects.

Alternatively, you could set up a pre-build step in your C# project that directly runs nmake, msbuild or even NAnt.

Answer (score 1):

Msbuild is what is used to build your projects when you hit the Play button. Personally I like [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) + [NantContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) it was easier for me to pick up and start using right away. For all new projects I use [tree surgeon](http://www.codeplex.com/treesurgeon) this tool creates a default build script and proper build tree with testing project and code coverage report.